# What's the equivalent of HttpContext.Current.User in an HttpListener-hosted service?

Tags: servicestack, httpcontext, httplistener, httplistenerrequest

I've written a custom attribute for ServiceStack that has the following code in it:

```
public override void Execute(IHttpRequest request, IHttpResponse response, object requestDto) {
    HttpContext.Current.User = GetUserFromOAuth2BearerToken(request);
}
```

This works beautifully when hosting in IIS, but when using the built-in HttpListener host, HttpContext.Current returns `null`.

What's the correct syntax to set, and get, the security principal associated with the current request/response when using HttpListener?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure the 'security principal/System.Security.Principal' is available with the current request/response when using `AppHostHttpListenerBase`.

You could pull get the User inforamation doing something like...

```
var sessionId = request.Cookies["ss-id"].ToString();
var user = request.GetCacheClient().Get<AuthUserSession>(sessionId);
```

Comment: Nice idea, but I'm using OAuth2 authorisation, which is stateless so there's no notion of a session cookie or a user session... there's a custom attribute on the methods which assigns the current HTTP context principal based on the OAuth2 bearer token. I might be able to do it using System.Threading but would rather not...